# SLES12SP1: How to add memcached to the new Services Manager

Tags: services, init.d, sles, runlevel

I installed a new SLES 12 SP1 VM from the scratch with `memcached` from https://memcached.org/.

**My question:**
On SLES 12 the `/etc/init.d/<service>` notation has *gone*. It is now provided by the program `service name flags`. How can I add `memcached` to the service list so it is also seen by `YAST` and set the `runlevel` in order `memcached` is started when the VM starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, it was easier than I thought:

1. In the build `memcached-1.4.27/script` directory there is the file `memcached.service`
2. Copy this into the `/usr/lib/systemd/system` directory which contains all `service` files.
3. Create in the `/etc/sysconfig` directory the environment file `memcached` - as referenced in `memcached.service` with the following content in order YAST and the system can start `memcached`:

Example of the `memcached` file:

```
PORT=11211
USER=root
CACHESIZE=1000
MAXCONN=1024
```

That's it. Open `YAST`, search for `memcached` and enable it.